# Hide all DIVs with the same class and display others

Tags: jquery, templates, onclick

I'm making a template in different languages.

a bit about the template: there will be certain DIVs shown allways and the others changing according to the language.

I've created a [jsFiddle example witch works as I need](http://jsfiddle.net/N3pPM/2/), but I'm positive that it is not a correct way to do it...

```
$( "span.es" ).click(function() {
  $( "div#es" ).fadeIn()
  $("div#en").fadeOut()
  $("div#de").fadeOut();
});
$( "span.en" ).click(function() {
  $("div#en").fadeIn()
  $("div#es").fadeOut()
  $("div#de").fadeOut();
});
$( "span.de" ).click(function() {
  $("div#de").fadeIn()
  $("div#es").fadeOut()
  $("div#en").fadeOut();
});
```

Can anyone show me a simplified version?

P.D. The content on the template won't go one after another, it will be in different places and using the button's the language class will be changed on click event.

I hope I explained myself! If not, sorry!

In the picture you can see a layout, content in red will contain different languages
[image: Template layout with multiple languages]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="en lan" target="en">English</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="es lan" target="es">Español</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="de lan" target="de">Deutch</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="en">
        Content EN
    </div>
    <div class="es hidden">
        Content ES
    </div>
    <div class="de hidden">
        Content DE 1
    </div>
    <div class="de hidden">
        Content DE 2
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
var $lans = $('#container > div');
$( "span.lan" ).click(function() {
    var $target = $lans.filter('.' + $(this).attr('target'));
    $lans.not($target).fadeOut();
    $target.fadeIn()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Knd3G/)

Comment: But it doen't work as I want it to... http://jsfiddle.net/Knd3G/2/

It should display all the div's with the same id.

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` instead of `hide()` and `show()`

Comment: This I know, but as I explained, there will be multiple content with the id of corespondig language, so the code should display all of them.

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas in that case you should not use id, you need to use class attribute

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas: IDs must be unique, use a class instead, something like "content-en", then remove `#` from `target` and have this as first line in click: `var $target = $(".content-" + $(this).attr('target'));` (although data-* attributes are better in my opinion)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you post a jsFiddle example with clases? Sorry, I'm not very strong at this. Thanks.

Comment: @ArunPJohny awesome! Thank you, now I will try to understand what is happening there. Works great, but I don't understand it, haha.

Comment: here is the final code with will work perfectly for me! Thanks again @ArunPJohny http://jsfiddle.net/Knd3G/5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, can you modify the script, so it would add a class to a clicked element? Ex. you click on span EN and active class..

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas to which element `li` or `a`

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas but in the fiddle to which element

Comment: @ArunPJohny in the listing on load of the page one of the `<p>` element's will have this class added (default lang) then when clicked it should remove the class from other elements and add that class to the clicked one... for me it's to complicated to write a script like that....

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas can you prepare a fiddle with the required markup

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas from whatever we had you can look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Knd3G/7/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35931/discussion-between-arturas-strazdas-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/7Yp74/

You apply the classes:

`lang lang-en` or `lang lang-es` or `lang lang-de` to the panels you wish to toggle.

When a button is clicked, you hide ALL the panels using `.lang` as the selector, then depending on the button clicked, use either `.lang-en`, `.lang-es` or `.lang-de` to show the selected one.

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Cache the items, and only assign a single `onclick` event, using `hasClass` to determine the class associated:

```
var $es = $("#es"),
    $en = $("#en"),
    $de = $("#de");

$( "span" ).click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('es')){
        $es.fadeIn();
        $en.fadeOut();
        $de.fadeOut();
    } else if($(this).hasClass('en')){
        $en.fadeIn();
        $es.fadeOut();
        $de.fadeOut();
    } else {
        $de.fadeIn();
        $es.fadeOut();
        $en.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Or even better, give them all another class like `countryClick` and do this:

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
    var $id = $(this).attr('class').split(' '); // gets first class, es for example

    $('#'+$id[0]).fadeIn();
    $('.countryClick').not('#'+$id[0]).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Although I am sure there could be a better way to do this as well.

```
$('span').click(function () {
    var spanClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#container div:not(#' + spanClass + ')').fadeOut();
    $('#container div#' + spanClass).fadeIn();
    //$('#container div#' + spanClass).fadeIn();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put the code here

http://jsfiddle.net/N3pPM/3/

```
$( "span.es" ).click(function() {
    $("div.lang").fadeOut()
    $( "div.english" ).fadeIn()
  });
$( "span.en" ).click(function() {
    $("div.lang").fadeOut()
    $("div.spanish").fadeIn()
});
$( "span.de" ).click(function() {
    $("div.lang").fadeOut()
    $("div.deutch").fadeIn()
});
```

Its a good idea if you want to hide a group of divs by providing a common class name 
and then hiding showing the divs based on this class name.
Here i have added class "lang" to all divs and "english","spanish","deutch" to divs for specific language.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following, this way you can expand and use as many languages as you choose in the future:

```
$('span').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + clicked).fadeIn(500,function() {
        $('#container div:not(#' + clicked + ')').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N3pPM/5/

Update: After looking at your screenshot layout, you will need to use classes, not IDs, the updated code is below:

**jQuery**

```
$('span').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#container .' + clicked).fadeIn(500,function() {
        $('#container div:not(.' + clicked + ')').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <ul>
    <li>
        <span class="en">English</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="es">Español</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="de">Deutch</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="en">
        Content EN
    </div>
    <div class="es">
        Content ES
    </div>
    <div class="de">
       Content DE
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/N3pPM/6/

Comment: Had to update it for the class/ID issue, you can't have more than one instance of an ID per page, and you need different sections for the language content.

Comment: As a quick explanation of the jQuery, you store the language you want in a variable, and then fade in the one that was clicked, and on the callback of the fadeIn function, call the fadeOut of all the others that do not have the class of the clicked element. If this is the solution you go with, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: It's a good answer as well, but I've already chosen the suitable answer for me. But Thank you a lot for the effort.

Comment: No worries, glad you got your help! I added that comment before I saw you had accepted an answer.